# Array memory management

Tags: c, memory-management, ubuntu, numa

I am doing my Computing Science project.  I am doing Multiprocessor programming using C.  One requirement for us it that, we cannot keep allocating small chunks of memory.  Memory can be allocated in big chunks when needed.

So imagine I use structures in my program.  And the way that my program works requires dynamic memory allocation.  But it is very costly in the hardware that we are using.   So the best solution would be to allocate a big pool of memory at the beginning and whenever needed allocate memory from this pool.

The way I envision this to work is that, I will allocate a bit array of these structures and write my own memory management module which allocates and frees memory from this pool.  But I want to know the most ideal way to write these modules.  Are there any libraries which can assist me in managing memory or is there some way that these can be written?

EDIT: Here is the platform that I use: an AMD opteron system which runs Ubuntu.  The opterons has NUMA architecture and I want to make use of this when allocating memory.  Hence instead of using malloc, I use **numa_alloc_onnode**  which allocates memory on one specific node.  I want to allocate a big chunk of memory using this and then use a memory manager to manage this memory.

Comment: I'm sure there are libraries that would be helpful, but without knowing the platform and OS, it would be difficult for anyone to recommend one.

Comment: @Carey: Most memory management systems I have worked with are fairly platform-agnostic (run wherever C is available), though knowing about particular system constraints e.g. embedded system certainly is important.

Comment: @Eric: Embedded systems are why I mentioned it.  The OP seems to imply he's using an unusual platform, which possibly means an unusual OS, or no OS at all.

Comment: Look up how *free lists* work. There are ways to implement them inside the storage itself, with no space overhead (though there's some searching overhead for allocations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a ton of memory pool managers out there, some commercial and some open source. Have a look at them, and feel free to ask more specific questions here after you have an overview.

Some google results (c memory pool manager open source):

http://256stuff.com/sources/mpool/

http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/

Here's a good article from IBM on the subject:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-memory/

And since you mention a multiprocessor environment (although not directly related to memory management), this is also a worthwhile read:

http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=217500206

**UPDATE**

There are different approaches depending on the desired portability of the library.  If portability is important, the library presents a wrapper around malloc (or calloc) to grab chunks of memory and then apply a more efficient implementation (as measured against the particular goals the library wants to achieve).  A library that targets a specific OS will typically use native operating system calls, gaining some performance and the ability to leverage specifics of that operating system at the cost of portability.

The specific goals that memory management libraries strive for vary.  Here are some goals I have seen over the years:

- Separate management strategies for large vs. small objects
- Separate management strategies for things that will live long vs. things that will be deleted rapidly
- Debugging for memory management issues (e.g. write a specific pattern into allocated memory and allocate some extra padding on the end so that a debug function can see if the padding was overwritten by an out-of-bounds pointer access)
- Faster memory access given constraints of a particular platform (e.g. some allocations may be expensive, others relatively cheap).
- Support memory defragmentation (e.g. by really allocating a pointer to a pointer, with special semantics for accessing memory).

**UPDATE 2**

Based on your update... my fourth bullet point applies.  Here's a good read on creating a heap manager for a NUMA architecture (source code at the end of the article):

http://ebookbrowse.com/numa-aware-heap-memory-manager-article-final-pdf-d12526838

Comment: Hi Eric, I looked up these links.. If I understood them right, they use their own memory allocator and get the memory from the operating system.  But in my case, I need to use a specific call that is specific for this architecture to get the chunk of memory.  Then the memory manager has to use this chunk of memory and manage it.. Is there any memory manager that can satisfy this?

Comment: Started to write a long comment, then decided it better to update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer based on the fact you're on a NUMA platform.